# Como uso el for each con rango para recorrer el correo a enviar y el correo de copia

Tags: macros

Amigos
Me gustaría saber como recorrer dos filas en un for each con range, quiero recorrer la fila de correo y la fila de el correo de copia.

For Each cell In Range("C2:C4")

```
    If cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
    
    Else
```